# Using optional complex type action parameter for a POST Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-post, restful-architecture

I am trying to write an API with the following prototype:

```
[HttpPost]
public ApplicationStatus appLogIn(string id, UserCredentials userCredentials = null)
```

But when I make a request to this API, with or without `userCredentials`, I get the following error with response code as `500`

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Optional parameter 'userCredentials' is not supported by 'FormatterParameterBinding'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": null
}
```

If I do not make the userCredentials as optional, everything works fine. The userCredential definition is as follows:

```
public class UserCredentials
{
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this has the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236527/asp-net-web-api-formatter-parameter-binding-exception

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the API definition to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ApplicationStatus appLogIn(string id, UserCredentials userCredentials)
```

As UserCredentials is a reference type, if client doesn't provide a value it will be set to null